# How to return to the DOM a string variable from controller that contains an html image tag with asset() function in src?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am facing an issue with Laravel 9.
In my controller, I have created a variable which contains inside quotes the html code to be returned to the view.

I have a problem to determine where I should use single quotes and double quotes or backticks so that the {{asset()}} in the image src is compiled properly.

for now my image url looks like this in the console :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20asset(storage/upload/test2-png.png)%20%7D%7D

Here is the error in the console:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20asset(storage/upload/test2-png.png)%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Here is the variable I am talking about:

```php
$celebrityDetailsContent = `
                @if(isset($celebrityClicked))
                    <div id="celebrity_text_and_picture_container" class="w-100 p-3">
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/upload/'.{$celebrityClicked->image}) }}" class="float-start img-border-radius img-thumbnail w-50 m-3" alt="Celebrity photo" title="Celebrity photo">
                        <p class="fw-bold">{$celebrityClicked->firstname} {$celebrityClicked->lastname}</p>
                        <p class="text-start">{$celebrityClicked->description}</p>
                    </div>
                @else 
                    <h2 class="fw-bold">Click on a celebrity to display details</p>
                @endif
            `;

            return $celebrityDetailsContent;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `{{ }}` in your controller. It only works in your `blade` files. Try this:

```
if (isset($celebrityClicked)) {
    $celebrityDetailsContent = '
                <div id="celebrity_text_and_picture_container" class="w-100 p-3">
                    <img src="' . asset('storage/upload/' . $celebrityClicked->image) . '" class="float-start img-border-radius img-thumbnail w-50 m-3" alt="Celebrity photo" title="Celebrity photo">
                    <p class="fw-bold">' . $celebrityClicked->firstname . ' ' . $celebrityClicked->lastname . '</p>
                    <p class="text-start">' . $celebrityClicked->description . '</p>
                </div>';
} else {
    $celebrityDetailsContent = '<h2 class="fw-bold">Click on a celebrity to display details</p>';
}

return $celebrityDetailsContent;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Molod. It works fine. Just one thing, I have edited my code in my question. Do you know how to do the same with blade condition (see edited code above) ? @Molod

Comment: @Younes, i have edited my answer, try this code. And again: don't use blade directives in your controller. Use plain php